# Moving into new house, neighbours have sensitive dog

Tags: dogs, behavior, socializing, vocalizations

I am moving house and on visits to inspect the property before moving in, the neighbours dog would bark very aggressively whenever I went out to the back garden. The dog does not bark when I am inside the house. There is a big fence between the houses so the dog can't see me and I can't see the dog and the dog can't get through.

What can I do to stop this barking? Is it just a case of "introducing" myself to the dog and how to ask the neighbour to arrange this.

Also, I hope to get a new dog too so should I do something similar with this new dog?

I won't be accepting any answers though until the occasion has passed and this could be a while in the making.

Comment: You should first know what's it's issue so you can know what to do about it. Because it may be afraid, terretorial ,you did something wrong in the eyes of the dog when you passed by or it can even be sick. I'm afraid you haven't given  enough details for a full answer. And it's better to learn more about the neighbo's dog before bringing in any pets to secure their safety.

Comment: Related question from perspective of dog owner [How can i stop my dog being aggressive with people passing by](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10338/)

Answer (score 4):

You could introduce yourself to the dog.

Have some treats or little pieces of sausage or cheese in your pocket. Go to the fence and gauge whether the dog is protective (barking without snarling) or agressive (snarling). If the dog is snarling, talk to your neighbor but don't approach the dog any further.

If the dog isn't snarling, stand relaxed at the fence, turned sideways and ignoring the dog for a short while. Let him sniff you to become farmiliar with your scent.

Then you turn to him and talk to him like "Hey you, are you guarding you fence?". The content doesn't matter, what's important is to sound friendly. Offer him your hand to sniff, but don't touch him during this first encouter. That's a way to show your respect to the dog and a great foundation for your mutual friendship.

Repeat the procedure whenever he barks at you (even if you don't have treats with you). Calmly walk to him, talk to him friendly, first let him sniff you and only then pet him if he lets you.

Comment: It's also probably worth noting that you should ask the owners permission before giving the dog anything to eat. It may not be able to eat certain foods or have a health issue.

Answer (score 3):

This usually is the case with very 'protective dogs.' They feel you're a traitor to the territory of their previous neighbors because you are a stranger to them. It will take some time until the dog gets used to you. You should talk to its owner so they can slowly start introducing you to the dog. Once you're familiar to the dog, it would (and should) stop barking aggressively.

Comment: One thing to add to this is you should probably do the same with your potential new dog too.